# The sms verification code used to create the phone auth credential is invalid

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart, firebase-authentication

how can i solve this issue am getting.. have implemented Phone authentication in my Flutter app. the Sms code is Sent on my Device but am having issues Verifying the Sms Code which is Sent. how can i solve this?

```
 this is the error:
   [firebase_auth/invalid-verification-code] The sms verification code used to create the phone auth credential is invalid
```

HERE IS MY VERIFYPHONE FUNCTION :

```
await  _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
             phoneNumber: _phoneController.text.toString().trim(),
             verificationCompleted: (phoneAuthCredential)async{
                 setState(() {
                   showloading = false;
                 });

                 signInWithPhoneAuthCredentials(phoneAuthCredential);
             },
             verificationFailed: (verificationFailed)async{
               setState(() {
                 showloading = false;
               });
               // ${verificationFailed.message}
              _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: new Text("VerificationFailed::${verificationFailed.message}" )));

              debugPrint("ERROR PHONE VERIFY::::: ${verificationFailed.message}");
             },
             codeSent: (verificationId, resendingToken)async{

             setState(() {
               showloading = false;
               currentState = MobileVerificationState.SHOW_OTP_FORM_STATE;
               verificationCode = verificationId;

             });
             },
             codeAutoRetrievalTimeout:(verificationId)async{

             });
```

Comment: Hard to say what can be wrong without seeing how you implemented the phone auth or if you use some plugins for that? Did you test it? You have to add any fake number in Firebase console + a code for testing during debug.

Comment: Are you following that medium article with green background colors? If so, remove the `sms code "xxxx"` in your `codeSent` function.

Comment: have Edited my post please check...